# How to access and change the property of a label that I created dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanna change the `Text` properties of `Label` using `Button`s just like in hangman; but after I created the `Label`, I became confused when I try to access the *specific Label*

```
// creating label
for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
{
    Label l = new Label();
    l.Text = "_";
    l.Width = 20;
    l.Height = 25;
    l.Left = i * 20 + 510;
    l.Top = 20;
    l.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    groupBox2.Controls.Add(l);
}

// function to change the label text
// if I clicked the button
// the first label text will be changed to the text in the button i clicked
private void B_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var thsBtn = (Button)sender;
    bool benar = false;

    if (benar == false)
    {
        thsBtn.Text = " ";

        thsBtn.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        thsBtn.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code with your attempt to _access a specific label_? If you don't give them a Name then you will have a difficult time to retrieve a specific label

Comment: so i must give the label a name after create the label?

Comment: `((Label)groupBox2.Controls[0]).Text = ....` ... of course you may store Labels in array for easier access

Comment: Since you're not storing a reference to the label anywhere other than in `groupBox2.Controls`, you have to use `groupBox2.Controls` to get your label again. The [`ControlCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection) implements `IList` (which implements `IEnumerable`) so you can use linq to query it. You can also use the provided indexer (`groupBox2.Controls[0]`) to get the control. Keep in mind that _every_ child of the groupbox is in there which could be more than just the labels you added.

Comment: @Selvin Thanks man I get it Now

Comment: @Joelius Thank you, I get it, I'm working on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *organize* created `Label`s into a collection, say, `List<Label>`:

```
   private List<Label> m_CreatedLabels = new List<Label>();

   ...

   // Remove all previous labels 
   foreach (Label lbl in m_CreatedLabels)  
     lbl.Dispose();

   m_CreatedLabels.Clear();       

   // Create new ones 
   for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++) {
     m_CreatedLabels.Add(new Label() {
       Text      = "_",
       Width     = 20,
       Height    = 25, 
       Left      = i * 20 + 510,
       Top       = 20,
       BackColor = Color.Transparent,
       Parent    = groupBox2
     });
   }
```

Now you have `m_CreatedLabels` collection to work with created `Label`s, e.g.

```
private void B_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var thsBtn = sender as Button; 

  // you may want to add a condition into FirstOrDefault(), e.g. 
  //   .FirstOrDefault(lbl => lbl.Text == "_") 
  // - first label with "_" Text
  Label lblToProcess = m_CreatedLabels
    .FirstOrDefault(); 

  if (null != lblToProcess) 
    lblToProcess.Text = thsBtn.Text; 

  thsBtn.Enabled = false; 
}
```

Comment: Wow thats a lot of help, Thank you. I'm going to try it

Answer (score 0):

One option here is to give your dynamically created `Label` instances a `Name`. From there, you should be able to use [`ControlCollection.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find) to find your `Label` instances by name.

```csharp
private void CreateLabels()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
   {
      Label l = new Label();
      l.Name = $"DynamicLabel{i}";
      l.Text = "_";
      l.Width = 20;
      l.Height = 25;
      l.Left = i * 20 + 510;
      l.Top = 20;
      l.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
      groupBox2.Controls.Add(l);
   }
}

private void DoSomethingWithADynamicLabel(int dynamicLabelIndex)
{
   Label l = groupBox2.Controls.Find($"DynamicLabel{i}", true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
   if (l is null)
   {
      // Couldn't find the label...
      return;
   }
   // Do something with l
}
```

When creating the `Label` instances inside `CreateLabels`, I'm simply appending the `for` loop's counter to the string `"DynamicLabel"`. This gives you a bunch of `Label`s with names like `"DynamicLabel0"`, `"DynamicLable1"`, `"DynamicLabel2`", etc...

Then in `DoSomethingWithADynamicLabel`, assuming you have the index of the `Label` you want to deal with, you can use `groupBox2.Controls.Find` to actually find the `Label` you're interested in. `ControlCollection.Find` returns `Control[]`, so calling `FirstOrDefault` will take the first item from the array or `null` if no `Control` with the given name exists.